# Decomposition of posterior porbability

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem, data-analysis, parameter-estimation

So, I'm currently working through "Data Analysis: A Bayesian Tutorial 2nd Ed." by D.S. Sivia and I am stuck an equation, which I am not able to reproduce (p.40 - 42 for those who might have a copy).

A little background: we want to estimate amplitudes $A$, $B$ of a gaussian peak and its background of data points $N_{k}$. Additionally, the width $w$ and position $x_{0}$ are also variable parameters, resulting in the following posterior expression:

$$
prob(A, B, w, x_{0} | \{N_{k}\},  I)
$$

The author then goes on to decompose the above expression with the help of Bayes Theorem:

$$
prob(A, B, w, x_{0} | \{N_{k}\},  I) \propto 
prob(\{N_{k}\} | A, B, w, x_{0}, I) \times prob(A, B, w, x_{0} | I).
$$

Now is the point where I lose the author who claims that the 2nd part of this equation can be further decomposed as:

$$
prob(A, B, w, x_{0} | I) = prob(A, B | I) \times prob(w, x_{0} | I)
$$

With the rules which were developped this far into the book, I actually cannot reproduce this result. I tried it with (what the author calls) the "product rule" stating

$$
prob(X, Y | I) = prob(X | Y, I) \times prob(Y, I).
$$

However, this would result in 
$$
prob(A, B, w, x_{0} | I) = prob(A, B | w, x_{0}, I) \times prob(w, x_{0} | I)
$$
and it would assume that setting $X = A, B$ and $Y = w, x_{0}$ is a valid thing to do.

If someone sees the point I am missing, it would be really great of you to help me out.

Comment: Maybe $A,B$ are independent from $w, x_0$?

Comment: @manonlaptop That sounds reasonable and would presumably lead to the equality of $prob(X | Y, I) = prob(X | I)$. This might be implicitly asumed in the book. However, I am not really sure that's the case. I would argue that the amplitude of a guassian peak actually depends on the peaks width, thus they would not be independent, right? In any case thanks for the help.